# How can I resolve different entities from an id in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

**Some Background to my application:**
I'm developing a Discord-Bot in Java using Spring Boot, Spring Boot Data JPA and JDA.
The bot is supposed to have several buttons in Discord with different purposes. When a user clicks a button, the bot gets the id (which I gave it beforehand when I created it) of the button in an event-handler.

**Different example scenarios:**

1. Button1 with the id 20 resolves to a role-button-entity with Role1, so the Member gets Role1 assigned.
2. Button2 with the id 32 resolves to a ticket-button-entity with some logic that runs on click.

(The different button entities also have different fields)

**Question:** How can I design something like this?

One option that came to my mind is to have a generic-button-entity, so that JPA's id represents the id from the button in Discord and it stores another id (e.g.,from a role-button-entity, to run its logic with its fields instead of the ticket-button-entitiy's logic/fields).
Does this option make any sense and if so, is it possible to cascade the `Long buttonEntityId` with e.g. the role-button-entity?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean different types of buttons with some common fields and some different fields?

Comment: The fields that both will have is only the id, the rest of the fields will be different

Comment: So, is thos a JPA problem? From an entity-design point of view that would be two different entities with only common thing to be uave "button" in there names. Would be that so? Or may be O'm not getting it right.

Comment: Yeah exactly. But I need resolve those ids in something like the following flow:
User clicks button -> Event handler is called with id -> get button (so role-button or ticket-button, at this point I don't know the type of button wich is corresponding to the id) from database -> call a role-handler or ticket-handler based on button-entity type and do some logic in the handlers.

Comment: I wouldn't use an Id to discriminate a type of element, but a specific `type` attribute. Can't you create the buttons with a `type` attribute (Ideally managed by an `enum`, but a plain `String` can perfectly fit) that could be used to call the handler with?

Answer (score 0):

There are some dessign patterns that would fit in your business case. A `Factory` for instance to decide which button type to create, or a `Strategy` to decide which behaviour to perform.

But either way, every one needs to take a path or another based on some parameter/attribute/property. You are saying that you want to use the `ID` of the element to do so, that is the same `ID` that would be used as the `PRIMARY KEY` in the ddbb. So meaning two different independent tables, but with a shared uniquenes in the `ID`...

That, as almost everything in software, can be achieved, but it's a clear code smell, a design smell. Using some id as a discriminator, not for the id value itself, but for the data it represents... Doesn't make sense.

You can manage to do it, but the solutions you're gonna use, the workarrounds you'll have to perform, and the pitfalls that all that would imply will definitely make your code less readable, maintainable and scalable.

A path that would make much more sense is a specific property bound to the buttons that specify the type it is, and use this in the patterns/logic to do/create either one think or another. Efforts towards this solution will give you much better results.

Regarding the database representation of this solution, unless you find a reason why, you don't even need to have a `TYPE` column, as that can be directly inferred from the TABLE/entity, meaning that it can directly be a constant in the entity.

**Update**

Ok. I think you are mixing here different concerns. The entities should represent data. What is the purpose of having the buttons in the database? They are not data, but presentation. Roles are data, tickets are data, but buttons are not data (unless is a specific type of application in which you build buttons).

I would have a `@Component` for each button type with all the business logic related to that button type.

```java
@Component
public class RoleButtonHandler {

    public doRoleStuff(...) {
        // do roles stuff
    }
   
}
```

```java
@Component
public class TicketButtonHandler {

    public doTicketsStuff(...) {
        // do tickets stuff
    }
   
}
```

Then, instead of an entity, I would just have an enum representing the different button types:

```java
public enum ButtonType {
    ROLE(20),
    TICKET(32);

    private static Map<Integer, ButtonType> ID_VALUES_MAP = Arrays.stream(values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(b -> b.id, b -> b));

    public int id;

    ButtonType(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ButtonType getButtonTypeFromId(int id) {
        return ID_VALUES_MAP.get(id);
    }
}
```

And in the event handler, you receive the `id`, you obtain the ButtonType, and based on that you call one component or the other one.

With this approach, even if you want to keep the buttons in the database, which would be in different tables, as you said they have completely different fields, you can easily do that in the dedicated `@Component`, seamlessly.

**Improvement**

I don't know if this is your case, but if you reveice the ID of the button via json in a rest service, and the ID of the button is decided by you, you can make it a `String`. In that case the `enum` can have only the values, because translating from json to enum that has the same `String` value is automatic, without the boilerplate of translating everything by hand. And the code is more readable.

Comment: You mean that the id of the button in Discord is something like (btw. the button id in Discord is always a String) `ticket-12`, while `ticket` represents the type and `12` the entity id in JPA?

Comment: What is the information you want to save in the database? one row per button click? or one row per button that exists.

Comment: I would like to store one row per existing button with information such as the role ID (in the case of the role button), the user who created the button and when they created it. 
Do you think the approach to create buttons with an ID of e.g. `role-1`, `role-2` etc. and store `role`/`ticket` in an enum as a string as you wrote: `ROLE("role"), TICKET("ticket");` be suitable for my use case? (and in the button handler split the ID at `-` and call the specific handler by the type from the enum with the jpa ID [only the number])

Comment: No, sorry. I thought you created the buttons and the user only clicked them, and your bot reacts on click events. You are telling then that the users can create buttons?

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself unclearly. I (with other admins) create the button via REST endpoints, which then attach the button to a Discord message (at this point I can give the buttons any string [ID] I want [e.g. `ticket-3`]) and saves it to the database. Then when a user clicks on the button, a ButtonClickHandler is called with the ID (which is a string) of the button. Based on this ID, I want to call the appropriate handler (e.g. ticket or role button handler) and load the button from the database into this handler and then do some stuff with it.